# How to set BindingContext without instantiating a new ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a common viewmodel with an image and an event that is subscribed to when the viewmodel is created. This event listens to changes in wifi connectivity and changes the image to a wifi on or off icon. In another viewmodel, connected to a specific view, I want to bind an image to the image present in the common viewmodel. The problem is, setting the binding context of this image to the common viewmodel instantiates another copy of the common viewmodel. Now I have two of these common viewmodels and the event fires twice, once for each viewmodel. How can I prevent this from happening?

Edit:
The binding context for the page that wants to access the image in the common viewmodel is let's say MyViewModel. The binding context of the image is set to the common viewmodel like so:

```
<Image
    Source="{Binding ConnectivityImageSource}">
    <Image.BindingContext>
        <connectivity:CommonViewModel />
    </Image.BindingContext>
</Image>
```

Comment: Since we are software people here, we understand code better that text. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue so we can suggest you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> setting the binding context of this image to the common viewmodel instantiates another copy of the common viewmodel

This is not true, if you use one viewmodel you will have just one instance. You need to pass the reference of it and bind it to another view, which you clearly don't do. It is hard to say how you should do it as there are multiple ways to do it, but here is one:

```
public class Page2: ContentPage
{
  public Page2(object viewModel)
  {
     BindingContext = viewModel;
  }
}
```

EDIT: you have change the question quite a lot, but the answer is essentially the same - you need to pass the reference of the common viewmodel and not to initialize it twice like you do it. Again, there are multiple ways to do it, and you can start with the sample above, just then don't assign the model as binding context of the whole view but just of the control if it is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. The common viewmodel has been instantiated in the beginning of the app's lifetime to watch for connectivity changes. The binding context for the page that wants to access the image in the common viewmodel is let's say viewModel, while the binding context of the image itself is set to the common viewmodel through xaml, as seen in my edit, seemingly creating another instance. Is it not so?

Comment: @Zebrastian setting binding through XAML only intitiates the new CommonViewModel, so everything works as expected. You need to work like I said above, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may use singleton pattern or static definition to not initiate the viewmodel twice.

Here is a source about the singleton pattern: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try singleton pattern, sample code below

Your view model constructor should be,

```
public static SampleViewModel currentInstance;
    /// <summary>
    /// Currents the instance this view mode shared on two place.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The instance.</returns>
    /// <param name="navigation">Navigation.</param>
    public static SampleViewModel CurrentInstance(INavigation navigation)
    {
        if (currentInstance == null)
            return currentInstance = new SampleViewModel(navigation);
        else
            return currentInstance;

    }
```

and your code behind binding context should be,

```
public SamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = SampleViewModel.CurrentInstance(Navigation);

    }
```